# Yii Framework Templating

Tags: php, frameworks, yii, templating

I'm pretty new to the Yii Framework, but as I was creating new projects I realized there are files that I want to add to each of those new projects that does not come with the framework. For example, an .htaccess file to turn on the rewriteengine or a plugin of some sort. Just wondering if I could get some pointers on this.

I apologize if this does not fall in "templating", that's the best I can think of. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @DCoder Let say for example, I have a current project that uses a jquery plugin and I want this plugin to be available for all my future Yii application. Is there a way I can include the plugin in future when running the yiic command from the terminal without having to copy and paste the plugin from older projects to new projects. Hope this clarifies what I'm looking for.

Comment: The `webapp` shell command is responsible for setting up the initial app skeleton. You can find its code in `framework/cli/commands/WebAppCommand.php` , you can either modify its code or write a new command that extends `WebAppCommand` and performs the additional tasks you need.

Answer (score 0):

For such things like a .htaccess I can't think of a Yii function of a template. In fact templates are only for look.

You could, however, make a "base" project from where you would start new projects if you want the same base functionality in all your projects. It's like making a base controller... I'm sure you get the point.

Comment: Base controller for added more defaults like .htaccess, some plugins ?

Comment: @Jorge Thanks for the pointer! I think I'm using the term "templating" incorrectly here. I'll look into base controller, sounds promising.